# Unix: Why is my error not triggering?

Tags: bash, unix

In filelist,
Update, filelist is a file

```
hello/noReadPermissions1.txt
hello/noReadPermissions2.txt
hello/noReadPermissions3.txt
```

the file has no read permissions `-w------`, however, directory has `700`, but I am trying to read the file.

```
while read line; do
[ ! -r "$line" ] && echo "Cannot Read this"
done < filelist
```

It's not triggering! I don't understand why, my one and only guess is: the test command is starting in another process. If so, what's a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works for me in bash:

```
while read line; do [ ! -r "$line" ] && echo "no file" ; done
```

gives me the file name as output if the file exists and is readable, and "no file" if not.

Are you using bash?

**Update:**

Wait, are you just trying to read the *contents* of the file?

then

```
if [ -r $filelist ]
then
   while read line
   do
     # something with line
   done < $filelist
fi
```

**Update 2:**

Okay, so you have something like

```
$ touch noreadme
$ chmod a-r noreadme 
$ ls -l noreadme 
--w-------  1 chasrmartin  staff  0 Dec 12 23:16 noreadme
```

and do

```
$ while read line; do [ ! -r "$line" ] && echo "no line" ; done < noreadme
```

and should get

```
-bash: noreadme: Permission denied
```

You never get your error message because before the while look even starts, the shell detects it can't read the file.  The `open(2)` call fails, and the whole line is ended.

Comment: It was actually a file, my mistake. I should say the file contains multiple lines.

Comment: Your answer would be easier to read if instead of treating it like a log, you edit your answer in-place to say what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for why your error will not trigger is if you are running as root. You will have permission to read the file regardless of the permissions on the file:

```
# touch /tmp/foo
# chmod 200 /tmp/foo
# ls -l /tmp/foo
--w------- 1 root root 0 Dec 13 21:03 /tmp/foo
# test -r foo && echo readable
readable
```

From this, you can see that the file tests as "readable" even though there is no read permission set on the file.

Comment: This answers the question how?

Comment: @Charlie Martin: The question in the title is "Why is my error not triggering?" I answered that if you are root then you will have permissions, even if it does not look like it. Hence the error will not trigger. How can I make this clearer?

Answer (score 0):

The test command is not running in a subshell and would produce output you can see even if it were. It's not entirely clear what you're doing. I believe you're doing one of these two things:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/readtest
$ cd /tmp/readtest
$ touch noReadPermission{1,2,3}.txt
$ chmod 200 noReadPermission{1,2,3}.txt
$ ls noReadPermission* > filelist
$ ls -l 
-rw-------  1 user  group  78 Dec 13 11:57 filelist
--w-------  1 user  group   0 Dec 13 11:57 noReadPermissions1.txt
--w-------  1 user  group   0 Dec 13 11:57 noReadPermissions2.txt
--w-------  1 user  group   0 Dec 13 11:57 noReadPermissions3.txt
$ while read line; do [ ! -r "$line" ] && echo "Cannot Read $line"; done < filelist
Cannot Read noReadPermissions1.txt
Cannot Read noReadPermissions2.txt
Cannot Read noReadPermissions3.txt
$ chmod a-r filelist
$ ls -l
--w-------  1 user  group  78 Dec 13 11:57 filelist
--w-------  1 user  group   0 Dec 13 11:57 noReadPermissions1.txt
--w-------  1 user  group   0 Dec 13 11:57 noReadPermissions2.txt
--w-------  1 user  group   0 Dec 13 11:57 noReadPermissions3.txt
$ while read line; do [ ! -r "$line" ] && echo "Cannot Read $line"; done < filelist
-bash: filelist: Permission denied
```

What part of this is not working for you or not working as expected?